# TfsTeamProjectCollection get service returns null for WorkItemStore

Tags: c#, tfs

I am experiencing a problem with getting work items from TFS server.
I have installed `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client`, `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client` and `Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient`

I have Windows form application with following method:

```
TfsConfigurationServer configurationServer = TfsConfigurationServerFactory.GetConfigurationServer(tfsUri);
CatalogNode collectionNode = configurationServer.CatalogNode.QueryChildren(new[] { CatalogResourceTypes.ProjectCollection }, false, CatalogQueryOptions.None).FirstOrDefault();
Guid collectionId = new Guid(collectionNode.Resource.Properties["InstanceId"]);
TfsTeamProjectCollection teamProjectCollection = configurationServer.GetTeamProjectCollection(collectionId);
var workItemStore = (WorkItemStore)teamProjectCollection.GetService(typeof(WorkItemStore));
```

All results before `teamProjectCollection.GetService` looks ok, however `workItemStore` is always null. Any ideas why i'm not getting service back?

I'm running Visual Studio 2015 on Win 10 x64.. Maybe it is to do with that?

UPDATED:
I found out this error

> Reference to type 'Team Foundation Server' claims it is defined in 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client', but it could not be found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After long day of debugging I found out that all reference must go to your start up project even though you are not using them it that project.... I have 5 different windows form projects on a solution and after adding those refs to startup project rest is working fine.... Not sure why or how but that fixed issue I had.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add references to individual libraries? Add the nuget package

Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient

It would add all dependent packages you need. I tried your code with the following package and it worked fine

```
<package id="Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient" version="15.112.1" targetFramework="net452" />
```